# Windows TeX Live Shell GUI Malfunctioning

Tags: errors, texlive, tex-core, tlmgr, texlive2022

When loading repository in the GUI an error immediately pops up saying `Error: key "texlive.infra" not known in dictionary`. The detailed error message is as follows:

```
key "texlive.infra" not known in dictionary
key "texlive.infra" not known in dictionary
    while executing
"dict get $::pkgs texlive.infra localrev"
    (procedure "get_packages_info_remote" line 17)
    invoked from within
"get_packages_info_remote"
    invoked from within
".pkfilter.upd invoke "
    invoked from within
```

After closing that error message another message saying `collect_filtered should not have been invoked at this time` appears, leading to a crash. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I have the same error, but I didn't find a solution.

Comment: Same here, googling does not help

Answer (score 1):

It helped for me to run TeX Live Shell with admin rights, so the issue was gone and I could update packages